# How to remove a single framework from Cocoapods Xcode 7

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I use the deintegrate framework for removing all pods when using Cocoapods. I made a mistake and added Google AdMob framework - I don't want to remove all pods, just this one. What is the process for doing so so that the removal is complete for just one pod in the project? Is the preferred way of doing this to deintegrate all and just add a Podfile back with just the ones you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove name of that library from the pod file and then run `pod install` command again. That should do it.

Comment: I saw the previously answered question but it was originally answered in 2012 with update in 2014 - just want to make sure it's still gonna work. `pod install` or `pod update`?

Comment: Even pod update will work. pod install is generally used first time while creating workspace.